# How to permanently attach USB devices to a KVM vserver?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, usb, libvirt, passthrough, virt-manager

I run a Server using KVM and virt-manager (over SSH). Currently I have the following devices which I want/need in a KVm virtual machine:

> +----USB-HUB
>
> +- USB Smartcard Reader #1
>
> +- USB Smartcard Reader #2

They have the following entries in lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 089: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 002 Device 088: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 002 Device 087: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub
```

As you can see the smartcard readers have the same Device and Product IDs. What I want to achieve is having these two readers *permanently* attached to my virtual machine. Is that even possible with KVM and libvirt? If so, how?

If not, would it work using VirtualBox (read a lot positive things about USB passthrough and VBox).

Answer (score 0):

I won't solve the problem, but here is a hint that might come in handy one day. The device is a Smargo Cardreader from Argolis. If it was updated to Version 1.5 or above it would have a distinct serial. With this distinct serial it's possible to edit the XML by hand. Little known, but it's possible to identify host devices in KVM via serial instead of the vendorXproduct tuple.

My solution: Brick the smargos while attached to a Laptop -> Stop worrying about the application they were ment for. ^^